# Displaying image in a new view controllers UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'll post my code first and then I'll explain the problem

**RootViewController.h its called SpViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import "secondViewController.h"
@interface spViewController : UIViewController


<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property BOOL newMedia;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) spViewController *secondViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *image;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *myImage;

- (IBAction)useCamera:(id)sender;


- (IBAction)useCameraRoll:(id)sender;


@end
```

**spViewController.m**

```
   #import "spViewController.h"
#import "secondViewController.h"

@interface spViewController ()

@end

@implementation spViewController

- (IBAction)backtohome:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
{
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)useCamera:(id)sender {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
             UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
            [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.sourceType =
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
            [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                               animated:YES completion:nil];
            _newMedia = YES;
        }
    }

- (IBAction)useCameraRoll:(id)sender {

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                           animated:YES completion:nil];
        _newMedia = NO;
    }
}



//image picker delegate

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; self.myImage =  chosenImage;

    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:info afterDelay:0.1];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        _imageView.image = image;
        if (_newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                           self,
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);
    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {

    }
}

-(void)myMethod:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Perform segue");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Picture Unwind Segue" sender:self];
    }];
}


-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                              message: @"Failed to save image"
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
//cancel delegate

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}



 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"Picture Unwind Segue"]) {
        secondViewController *destinationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        destinationViewController.imageView.image = self.myImage;
    }
}

@end
```

**secondViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import "spViewController.h"

@interface secondViewController : UIViewController

<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *myImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *image;

@end
```

**secondViewController.m**

```
#import "secondViewController.h"
#import "spViewController.h"

@interface secondViewController ()

@end

@implementation secondViewController



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.imageView.image = self.myImage;

    [super viewDidLoad];

         }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

So the problem I'm having is, I can't get the image that has just been selected in the `UIImagePickerController` to be displayed in the `UIImageView`, my `ImagePickerController` was initiated by a button in my previous view controller "`spViewController`" (`rootViewController`) I am using Storyboards, I thought if I put in the `UIImageView` then connected it using an outlet reference it would display there, this doesn't seem to be the case though. If I put the `UIImageView` in the first view controller and do the same it will display the image but thats not where I want it to go.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix my problem i decided to save the image and call on it later heres the code i put into my secondViewController.m

```
{NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *filepathJPG = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imagefile.jpg"];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: filepathJPG];
    if (img != nil) {
        // assign the image to the imageview,
        _imageView.image = img;

        // Optionally adjust the size
        BOOL adjustToSmallSize = YES;
        CGRect smallSize = (CGRect){0,0,100,100};
        if (adjustToSmallSize) {
            _imageView.bounds = smallSize;
        }

    }
```

I hope this can help others that have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So according to your code , you are setting the property of myImage which is an instance of UIImage from the RootViewController.

so your just passing the data of the image , But your not setting your `imageView.image` property to the passed image value.

So a possible fix would be to set 
`imageView.image  = myImage` in `viewDidLoad`

or

you can directly access the imageView property from the perform prepare for segue method in the RootViewController and set its image property.

I hope this helps . 
Cheers

Comment: sorry I'm very new to all this, its my first app, would you be able to explain in some more detail? thank your for your reply

Comment: Okay so there is an UIImageView and an UIImage instance, a UIImageView is just a container of an UIImage.So you are passing the UIImage to your SecondViewControler  , But still you need to tell your UIImageView to display the image. ..I hope this helps

Comment: so the code you gave in your answer, is that the code i need to use or is there a little more i need to do? thank you for explaining that did make sense :)

Comment: just set `imageView.image  = myImage` in your secondViewControllers `viewDidLoad`

Comment: i have tried that the image doesn't display, i did try before i commented but i couldn't seem to get it to work, Xcode wanted to change that line of code to
    _imageView.image  = _myImage;
i believe thats wrong though

Comment: _ (underbar) means your accessing the instance variable directly rather than through its setter and getter methods. you could silence the warning by prefixing "self." .Replace your last line in your RoothViewController prepare for segue method to `destinationViewController.imageView.image = self.myImage`

Comment: I have prefixed "self." at both the underbars and changed the 1 line of code you suggested, but the problem has not changed its still not displaying the image. thank you for your continuous help :)

Comment: Its okay , I have hunch that the problem doesn't lie in the way your passing the image , but i just went through your code again and your not saving the image you select in your imagePicker. Add this line `UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; self.myImage = chosenImage` at the top of the delegate method `-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`

Comment: ok i hadn't even realised that, didn't even cross my mind, i have now done so and I'm still have the same problem, I've updated the code above to show also, just to make sure i put it in the right place ;)

Comment: Haha , I'm Sorry Im not quite sure wants wrong . you could probably NSLog the image objects to check if its returning an image or may be try breakpoints to debug. Good luck ! :)

Comment: thank you, i actually figure the problem now using strings to save and then call the image to the uiimageview later, it now works... but only works in iOS simulator it doesn't seem to be working when i test the app on my really iPhone, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a property in AppDelegate class and access it across all controllers using appdelegate shared instance

Comment: not sure what you mean? i have already declared the property of my image, should i do it again in appDelegate.h?